# array from select of unnest in sqlalchemy postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

How can I produce the following sql in my select statement for postgresql in sqlalchemy ORM?

in a subquery I am trying to produce:

```
array(select distinct x from unnest(sm.setting_platform_ids || rm.rule_platform_ids) as x) as platform_ids
```

i tried

```
array(select(distinct(func.unnest(func.concat(sm.c.setting_platform_ids, rm.c.rule_platform_ids))))
```

to no avail.

then in the main query I am trying to produce:

```
array(select distinct x from unnest(array_agg(rs.platform_ids) filter (where rs.platform_ids <> '{}')) as x) as platform_ids
```

please advise. thank you

Comment: it seems to ultimately be a limitation that i cannot select into an array constructor with sql alchemy

Comment: Use array_agg() to create an array, not a subquery

Comment: @FrankHeikens i cannot use array_agg() unless I do a lateral join from the unnest. In which case I have to re-group by other columns which already have aggregate functions applied to them.

This issue is all a function of not being able to do an array union as an agg function. And not being able to do a distinct array concat, as well.

I'm not exactly a sql wizard but array from select distinct from unnest allows me to do this array union aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create a custom function in the db that produces the union between two arrays. I've named it `array_union`. I then wrap my array concat in it like so

postgresql `array_union(array_agg(a) || array_agg(b)) as somebs`

sqlalchemy `(func.array_union(func.array_agg(a) + func.array_agg(b))).label("somebs")`

I hold off on all aggregation until I get to my top level query.
Otherwise, you could create a custom agg union array function to aggregate at each subquery level